# Make a select with Linq using reflection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, backend

A few days ago I made a question: how could I made a insert into datatable taking the table name from a variable.

This was the solution:

```
var nameOfTable = "here I saved the name of table where i want to insert my information"

var type = ((IQueryable)db.GetType().GetProperty(nameOfTable).GetValue(db)).ElementType;
var dbSet = db.Set(type);
dbSet.AddRange(informationIWantToInsert);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Now I want to make something similar but this time I want to make a "dynamic" select, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM nameOfTable 
where foreign_key = number
```

I want to get all rows that meet the condition and y want to pass the name of table by variable.

Comment: DataTable results = table.AsEnumberable().Where(x => x.name = "abc").CopyToDataTable();

Comment: sorry it was my mistake. the variable table is a json with information that i insert into my data base. The important here is the variables type and dbSet

Comment: Your SQL used table.  So isn't the database then db.table.AsEnumerable()

Comment: Are you using reflection only to get a dynamic table name? I hope you know we can fire raw queries using EF. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql